# Java pass check does not work, conditions valid

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class p1_l2_adrian_costin {

  /*read string from keyboard*/
  public static String read() {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your password XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX \n");
      String password = keyboard.nextLine();
      return password;
  }

  /*check for number of words (4) and letters (5 per word), if ok pass true*/

  public static boolean splitAndCheckLength(String s) {
      String str[] = s.split("-");
      int counter = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
          if (str[i].length() == 5)
              counter++;
      if (counter == 4)
          return true;
      return false;
  }

  /*check for number of words compared to numbers, if there are more numbers than words pass true
   */

  public static boolean countNumbersAndLetters(String s) {
      String str[] = s.split("-");
      int counterL = 0, counterN = 0;
      char[] c;
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          c = str[i].toCharArray();
          for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
              if ((c[j] > 64 && c[j] < 91) || (c[j] > 96 && c[j] < 123))
                  counterL++;
              if (c[j] > 47 && c[j] < 58)
                  counterN++;
          }
      }
      if (counterN > counterL && counterL != 0) return true;
      return false;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      if (countNumbersAndLetters(read()) && splitAndCheckLength(read()))
          System.out.println("Good password");
      System.out.println("Bad password");
  }
}
```

problem is while evaluating each expression they both return true, but when putting them both in the if and trying to print a message from main everything stops working and it just starts again back to enter your password

Comment: You should probably `read()` once and pass the value to the methods, no ?

Comment: In general, if the check passes, or does not pass, while 'the conditiion is valid', with some debugging you find out that the Java code did exactly what you asked it to do.

Comment: Note that you should end up with a new "_"Enter your password XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_" that should give you a tip why your app stopped

Comment: thanks to all of you, figured it out now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you call `read()` twice, so after you call `countNumbersAndLetters()`, you ask for the password to be entered again.

You only want to get user input once:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = read();
    if(countNumbersAndLetters(input) && splitAndCheckLength(input))
        System.out.println("Good password");
    else 
        System.out.println("Bad password");
}
```